# determine if vector exists in transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the $R^2 \rightarrow R^3$ transformation how can I determine without RREF is the vector (1,3,5) exists in the $R^3$ co-domain of the transformation?

A = $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\\\ 4 & 5 \\\\ 6 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

I know the basis of the subspace is the vectors (1,4,6) and (3,5,1), but I'm still unclear how to quickly determine?  I am also aware the range of the subspace is all reals (x,y) in $R^2$

Comment: Some times the quickest way *is* to rref.  There are special cases, of course, where you can spot an answer immediately such as if you were asking if $(1,4,6)$ were in the columnspace, but for a general answer that works in all cases rref is often the go to method.

Comment: Really but isn't the subspace bounded by the 3rd equation namely z = 6x + y and can you not use that to determine if a vector (x,y,z) exists within the co-domain?

Comment: As you’ve defined the transformation here, its _codomain_ is all of $\mathbb R^3$. Do you mean to ask if $(1,3,5)^T$ is an element of its _range_?

Comment: Might not be any faster, but you could compute the $3\times3$ determinant.

Comment: @amd that would work for this specific case, but not in general.  The augmented matrix need not even be square.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to verify if there is a vector $[x , y ]$ such that 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 \\ 6 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x  \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\3 \\5 \end{bmatrix}$$
If it exists, then $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\3 \\5 \end{bmatrix}$ is in the co-domain.

So in our case, let's pick any $2 \times 2$ subsystem to solve (let's pick the first two)

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x  \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\3  \end{bmatrix}$$
which will give 
\begin{align}
x^* &=     0.5714 \\
y^* &=    0.1429
\end{align}
Now verify if the solution solves the third equation, that is 
$$6x + y =5$$
We get $$6x^* + y^* =3.5714 \neq 5 $$

Comment: And the method used to solve that smaller 2x2?  Still probably row reduction, especially in the generalized case where we have an arbitrary number of rows and columns.  I don't see how this explanation leads to a way to save time.

Comment: yeah no time saved. Instead it wastes time. But you can do it "quickly" as OP requests haha.